# VBA Excel - Variable "Double" as function

Tags: vba, variables, excel, double

I was given a VBA function that is working but I do not understand how it works and would appreciate your help because in the way it was written, the calculus is really long (basic arithmetic * 15 000 rows)

My problem comes from the definition of the Double variable Qty_Level which is defined as follow:

```
Dim Qty_Level(30) As Double
```

I have never seen a variable defined like this, with a couple of parenthesis like a function. Here's my code:

```
Sub cumul()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Qty_level(30) As Double
    Dim Col_Niveau As Integer
    Dim Col_Quantite As Integer
    Dim Col_Resultat As Integer

    i = InputBox("Veuillez indiquer le numéro de la première à analyser (numéro de     ligne Excel)", "Ligne de départ")
   Col_Niveau = InputBox("Veuillez indiquer le numéro de la colonne contenant les niveaux", "Niveaux")
   Col_Quantite = InputBox("Veuillez indiquer le numéro de la colonne contenant les quantités", "Quantités")
   Col_Resultat = InputBox("Veuillez indiquer le numéro de la colonne contenant les résultats", "Résultats")

   Do While IsEmpty(Cells(i, Col_Niveau)) = False

   If IsNumeric(Cells(i, Col_Quantite)) = True Then

        Qty_level(Cells(i, Col_Niveau).Value) = Cells(i, Col_Quantite).Value
        Cells(i, Col_Resultat).Value = 1

        For j = 1 To Cells(i, Col_Niveau).Value
            Cells(i, Col_Resultat).Value = Cells(i, Col_Resultat).Value * Qty_level(j)
        Next j

    End If

    i = i + 1

Loop


End Sub
```

I do not understand how this works, and particularly how the `For` loop works with the `Double(j)`

Comment: `Dim Qty_level(30) As Double` declares Qty_level as a 30 element array of Double.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan actually as a 31 element array :)

Comment: yep 31 welcome to VBA

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation for the VBA Dim statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243352%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). Actually, you may want to read up on [VBA arrays](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm) beforehand.

Comment: @varocarbas: Well, who know, maybe he has `Option Base 1`? :-)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett you are right :) the option exists. I meant by default (and by bearing in mind that using this option is not too common precisely).

Comment: `I do not understand how this works, and particularly how the For loop works with the Double(j)` Sorry I didn't understand what you are asking here...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys. I feel quite dumb now, the structure array(coordinates) is quite a classic but I'm still a newbie with VBA! 
@SiddharthRout : now I understand that the For loop is searching for each value in the array one by one

Comment: @varocarbas Thanks for the correction. I remembered VBA uses "()" to delimit dimension information, but not the extra element information.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan no problem. It is not an extra element, it just refers to different information (than what you are used to). In C# (or in other languages) this number stands for the Length/Size; in VB (and VBA), it refers to the Upper Bound of the array (its max. index).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `Dim Qty_Level(30) As Double` you're declaring a static array called `Qty_Level` containing 31 elements of type Double (double-precision floating-point), with lower bound 0 and upper bound 30. (Unless you wrote `Option Base 1` at the top of your module, in which case your lower bound is 1 and there are 30 elements total, but I doubt it.)

I see that in your current loop, you're starting your iteration at `j = 1` which means you never actually access element `0`. So it's better practice to explicitly specify your lower bound:

```
Dim QtyLevel(1 To 30) As Double
```

Comment: Yeah, you deserve the green V too but I felt like Ratafia needs to be encouraged a little more! Thanks for the remark though, it might be really helpful!

Comment: @alexc: to encourage a member you can always upvote but the answer which you should select should always be the one which actually answers  your question  ;-)  this is to ensure that the future visitors know which one actually helped  you  in case they have the same question...

Answer (score 4):

When you define an array with parentheses and a value inside them, it creates an array with that many elements contained within it. Dimensioning it with 30 as the max element value means that for a variable between 0 and 30 (since the array will start with 0 by default) you can store up to 31 values inside of the array. Dimensioning it as a double (according to MSDN) allows you to store the largest and smallest numbers available in Visual Basic.

What the loop appears to do is pull the quantity value from the quantity column based off of the number in the levels column, and then multiply each stored quantity value so far, storing it into the results cell.

So if your quantities are 2, 4, 6, 5, when you are at level 3 your result cell should show 48, and level 4 should show 240. Looping from 1 to the levels value allows it to iterate through the entire amount of stored quantities in the double array, which just contains numbers. The levels column should only contain numbers between 1 and 30, otherwise it will draw an error from the qty_level array.